# Difference between authentication and authentification?

Tags: differences, orthography

Is there any difference between authentication and authentification?
I was reading a question on SO where I saw somebody using 'authentication', was this a typo or dose these two words mean the same?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries? Both appear in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/authentification). There's even an explanation. I can't recommend either answer to the possible duplicated question of this site. The highly upvoted and accepted answer blames *authentification* on a non-native English speaker with zero evidence.